# Ubuntu 16.04 - AMD R9 390 video screentearing

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, tearing

I'm fairly new to Linux and Ubuntu, and I have some screen tearing issues in YouTube, chrome.

I think I managed to install this: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx but I can't be entirely sure.

Turning off hardware acceleration doesn't help.

Could it be as simple as the AMD driver I am using? I didn't really understand which driver I was supposed to actually use.

Comment: I don't have a solution but my R9 390 gets minor screen tearing in 14.04 so possible driver issue. I'm using FGLRX though where I'm assuming you are using AMDGPU

Answer (score 1):

AMD Radeon R9 390 is a GCN 1.1 GPU (HAWAII), so it should use the Radeon kernel driver, not amdgpu.

Speaking about "proprietary" drivers, you can't install **fglrx/Catalyst** drivers in Ubuntu 16.04 or later. AMD discontinued this driver before Xenial was released, so the **fglrx/Catalyst** driver doesn't support the 4.4 Linux kernel or newer. Don't try to do it, it's useless ;)

As far as I know, you have two alternatives:

- Install a newer version of Ubuntu (16.10...), which should have a better support for newer graphics cards thanks to the open source **Radeon** [1] or **Amdgpu** drivers. You can test Ubuntu 16.10 with a LiveUSB, but remember this release is supported only for only 9 months, then you can upgrade to Zesty.
- If you want to keep using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with kernel Linux 4.4 (supported until 2021), you can install the new "hybrid" AMD driver: AMDGPU-Pro [2]

[1] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver
[2] http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx